# How do I find which of my dependencies is downloading a particular jar?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojure-contrib

One of my project.clj's :dependencies is dependent on the monolithic clojure-contrib-1.1.0.jar, but I can't guess which one is downloading it. Short of incrementally commenting out each one, how can I discover which of them is responsible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a more Clojure-y solution, but you can run `lein pom` to generate a Maven POM, and then run `mvn dependency:tree` to display a tree of the projects dependencies.

Comment: Nope, this is the best you can do in Clojure at the moment.

Comment: At present, the better answer is to use `lein deps :tree` (an answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9971247/109618)

Answer (score 39):

This is available in leiningen now as `lein deps :tree`

See [here](https://refheap.com/paste/1273) for an example